# "[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component" on dynamic load

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to follow an code guide for a SimpleRouterApp, forked here:

https://github.com/pablo-mayrgundter/vue-3.0-simple-routing-example.

I'm trying to add sub-components to the example ones and get a "runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:36 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component:".  Debugging a bit, I find that the subcomponent is indeed defined, but the template resolution fails.  I don't know how to debug beyond this.. any pointers are appreciated!

```
<template>
  <coords-form ...></coords-form>
</template>
<script>
  import CoordsForm from '../coords/CoordsForm.vue';

  console.log('CoordsForm:', CoordsForm); // is valid in console
  export default {
    components: {
      'coords-form': CoordsForm
    },
    //...
</script>
```

If I import the component at the top level, it works fine.  So thinking maybe it's the dynamic load or some issue with webpack maybe?

I also tried doing a global registration as a workaround, but no luck

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, hard to say.  Have you been able to get his unmodified routing example to build and run? (not that simple IMO after looking a bit).  Also, if you haven't already, I recommend using the Vue DevTools plugin in your browser (Chrome or Firefox).  Among other things, you will see what components are loaded without having to console.log.

Comment: Yeah, unmodified works fine.  Good idea about Vue DevTools, but actually not detecting Vue in the page (again, despite un-modded example working fine).

The failing code is in the linked repo.. yarn install && yarn dev gets it running if you'd like to try it